# What is the default return type of flask endpoint's return statement?

Tags: flask

If we do not make use of render_template or markup or make_response or jsonify; and only use return "somevalue", then, what is the type of the response?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is HTML.
See their [reference](https://pythonspot.com/flask-hello-world/) with "Hello World"

Answer (score 0):

This is returning content-type: text/html;

Answer (score 0):

No you can't return some arbitrary value. The return type must be a string, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable otherwise you would get `TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response`. For string type response object is created with that data and the default parameters such as `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`. There is specific order in which tuple values can be used for return type `(response, status, headers)` or `(response, headers)` where at least one item has to be in the tuple. For WSGI callable you can set the headers however you want.

```py
def simple_resp(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    response_headers = [('Content-Length', '13')]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return ['Hello World!\n']

@application.route('/minion')
def minion():
    return simple_resp
```

And I think you already are familiar with `Response` type.

Answer (score -1):

It's a ResponseReturnValue that will be converted by [Flask.make_response()](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#flask.Flask.make_response) into a Flask.Response object.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.typing import ResponseReturnValue

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.get("/")
def index() -> ResponseReturnValue:
    return "hello world"
```

Comment: When I inspect what gets returned in the browser and via CLI or Python program, all that is returned is text.

Comment: @ChrisIvan that's because you are only looking at the returned value by the server (which is NOT only text, btw). You can check the docs yourself: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#flask.Flask.make_response